# catch text from a text editor and place them in a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here what i am doing is grab text which i write on my content editable div and place it in another div( like the one stack overflow has).Here i am facing a annoying problem.

1.My content div lagging behind.Means what i write on my editor it shows one character less in the content div.

2.Same thing happen when i press back space to delete  some character.I have to press  back space two times( that means delete two characters from text editor) to delete a single character from the content div

i want both the editor and content div go side by side.That means whatever i write or delete from the editor ,want the same thing for the content div.

How can i do that?

```js
var editor=document.getElementById('editor');
var content=document.getElementById('content');

editor.addEventListener('keypress',function(e){
         
          content.innerHTML=editor.innerHTML;
   
});
```

```css
      #editor{
      position:relative;
      width:500px;
   height:400px;
   border:1px solid black;
   word-wrap: break-word;
   padding-left:4px;
   padding-right:4px;
   padding-bottom:1em;
   box-sizing:border-box;
   overflow:scroll;
   }
   #content{
       position:relative;
      width:500px;
   height:400px;
   border:1px solid black;
   word-wrap: break-word;
   padding-left:4px;
   padding-right:4px;
   padding-bottom:1em;
   box-sizing:border-box;
   overflow:scroll;
   }
```

```html
<div id='editor' contenteditable='true' ></div>
<div id='content'></div>
```

Comment: try `keyup` instead of `keypress`. update your code like `editor.addEventListener('keyup',function(e){`here's a working jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/h1rtuLzz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using on `input` event, which will work even using `copy` and `paste` on context menu.

```
var editor=document.getElementById('editor');
var content=document.getElementById('content');

editor.addEventListener('input',function(e){ 
  content.innerHTML=editor.innerHTML; 
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rf1L8uhn/)

Comment: never thought of using..might come in handy .Thanks a lot :))

Answer (score 2):

Instead of binding a keypress even you can bind a keyup event. keypress would be fired once a key is pressed but the latest amendment would be only after keyup.

```
var editor=document.getElementById('editor');
var content=document.getElementById('content');

editor.addEventListener('keyup',function(e){

          content.innerHTML=editor.innerHTML;

});
```